# How to escape a percent sign in BigQuery queries?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We are attempting to select rows from a field in BigQuery that contains only a percent sign "%".

We have tried the answers to various other questions for escaping like this:

`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table WHERE field_name LIKE "\%"`

This gives an invalid escape character error with single or double quotes.

We also tried other variation escape characters shown for other flavors of SQL:

`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table WHERE field_name LIKE "!%"`

This gave us zero results as it didn't match the rows with percent signs.

We tried these queries in legacy and standard SQL.

**How do we escape a percent sign for SELECT/WHERE statements in standard SQL for BigQuery (and/or  legacy sql)?**

Comment: You say "only a percent sign". Why are you using `like` then? Is it for multiple occurences of "%"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest fix is below

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table WHERE field_name LIKE '%\\%%'
```

Meantime, another option is to use `REGEXP_CONTAINS` function (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(field_name, r'%')
```

For BigQuery Legacy SQL - you should use `REGEXP_MATCH` instead of `REGEXP_CONTAINS`