# SQL find '%' between %s

Tags: sql, syntax, google-bigquery, escaping

I need to find (exclude in fact) any results that contain `'%'` sign, wherever in a string field. That would mean `... WHERE string LIKE '%%%'`. Googling about escaping gave me the following ideas. The first throws syntax error, the second returns rows but there are records actually contain `'%'`.

1st:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE string NOT LIKE '%!%%' ESCAPE '!'
///tried with different escape characters
```

2nd:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE string NOT LIKE '%[%]%'
```

Trying on `GCP BigQuery`.

Comment: Try using a double backslash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923659/how-to-escape-a-percent-sign-in-bigquery-queries

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE string NOT LIKE '%!%%' {ESCAPE '!'}
```

With curly braces as shown in [microsoft sql server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/like-predicate-escape-character?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Or also:

```
WITH indata(s) AS (
            SELECT 'not excluded'
  UNION ALL SELECT '%excluded'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ex%cluded'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Excluded%'
)
SELECT * FROM indata WHERE INSTR(s,'%') = 0;
-- out       s       
-- out --------------
-- out  not excluded
```

Answer (score 0):

> find (exclude in fact) any results that contain '%'

Consider below simple approach

```
select *
from your_table 
where not regexp_contains(string , '%')
```